# Update RecyclerView adapter after SharedPrefereces changed

Tags: sharedpreferences, android-recyclerview, observers, android-sharedpreferences

I have `RecyclerView` with custom `RecyclerView` adapter.

Each row of `RecyclerView` "opens"(when user clicked on it) using CardFlipAnimation(`AnimatorSet`).

In each row there is a button that change int value in `SharedPreferences` , and `TextView` that shows this value.

If i have opened more than one row i need dynamically change all `TextViews` in all rows which are opened.

`NotifyDataSetChanged` and etc updates data in `RecyclerView` great but the is a problem that they close opened rows(because for standart thay are closed and then open with `AnimatorSet`)

My main mission now is to understand how to update only one `TextView` in all opened rows and to keep them opened(dont touch `AnimatorSet`).
I think i can use an `Observer`,but i didn't know how correctly implement him.

If you any ideas please help me.

Thanks for answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, finaly i got a solution , it's a little bit ugly but it works exactly as I need.

**First**: I pass my RecyclerView to Adapter

```
        ...
        public CardBaseAdapter(RecyclerView recyclerView,...) {
        ...
        this.mRecyclerView = recyclerView;
        ....
```

**Second**: Create a method in my Adapter :

```
    public void updateViews() {

        for(int i =0;i<getItemCount();i++){

            HeaderViewHolder holder = (HeaderViewHolder)recyclerView.findViewHolderForAdapterPosition(i);
            if(holder!=null){

             //Update views at holders
            }

        }

}
```

**Third**: Call this function when i need to update view

P.S. I'm not sure that this is the correct way to update view's , but it works, if you know another, good solution , post it pls